# Meteor fourseven:scss throws "file to import not found or unreadable"

Tags: meteor, sass, ionic-framework

I am using the meteoric package and I keep getting this error.

```
   client/style.scss: Scss compiler error: undefined
   /Users/lucanaterop/Desktop/lend/client/style.scss:3: file to import not
   found or unreadable:
   '.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/meteoric_ionicons-sass/ionicons.css.sass'
```

The error is known to disappear when the meteor server is restarted, but that doesn't happen. 
It only happens if I try to include the ionicons-sass:

```
@import '.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/meteoric_ionicons-sass/ionicons.css.sass';
```

It **does not** appear on the ionic-sass import:

```
@import '.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/meteoric_ionic-sass/ionic';
```

Answer (score 1):

There's currently an issue with the package right now... It's documented here: https://github.com/meteoric/ionicons-sass/issues/7

**Temporary solution until this get fixed (I got this off the same github page):**

Replace...

```
@import '.meteor/local/build/programs/server/assets/packages/meteoric_ionicons-sass/ionicons';
```

with...

```
@import 'http://code.ionicframework.com/ionicons/2.0.1/css/ionicons.min.css';
```

*(you can also choose to download the css and import it locally, but to do that you'll need to download the font files too and put it in ../public/fonts/...)*

Comment: This does not work on cordova. Works on desktop though, thanks.

Comment: @Pueggel you can download the css and import it locally for it to work on cordova (like you would importing any css files)

Comment: I can't get it running... I simply placed the "ionicons.min.css" in the public folder in meteor and include it using 
"@import 'ionicons.min.css';" 
Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: @Pueggel Sorry, I forgot to mention that you'll need to store the ionicon font files in `../public/fonts/...`. Also, there's no need to `@import` - meteor does the importing for us for regular css files.

Comment: @Pueggel if you check the console log, you can tell that the browser tries to download the font files from your server but fails: `Failed to decode downloaded font: http://localhost:3000/fonts/ionicons.ttf?v=2.0.1`